# jQuery fadein div reload multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kxYgiJ5cic#) and it works as i want, except that when the hidden div fadeIn, it reloads again and again when i hover it.

I want when i move the mouse on it to be stable and not reload multiple times.
Any suggestions?

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('h5').hover( function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hidd').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hidd').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/z5w4d46u/

Comment: @BG101  check the link he posted it's not really working in there lol

Comment: try this http://www.bootply.com/oQnVO78wMI

Comment: @BG101 sweet, that’s what exactly looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the `.hidd` is showing above the `h5` causing the mouse out of the `h5`:-

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('h5').mouseover( function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hidd').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  });
  $('.hidd').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

now when the `.hidd` shows infront the mouseout event will fire on leave of that instead.